# How do you write task lists in Spanish?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

In English:

> 1. Go to store.
> 2. Eat dinner.
>
>    ...

How would this be written in Spanish?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the same way as in English, but translating every task. Verbs **usually go in infinitive**. For example:

> 1. Ir al almacén.
> 2. Cenar.
> 3. Comprar leche.
> 4. Llamar al veterinario.

If it's a **shopping list** then we just put the items without any verb because the verb "comprar" (buy) is understood by the context. And you can add the amount if you want. E.g.

> 1. (12 l. de) leche.
> 2. (4) yogures.
> 3. (5 Kg. de) naranjas